# is new Router() and Router() identical in koa-router?

Tags: javascript, koa, koa-router

I saw the code that uses `koa-router` as below.

```js
const Router = require('koa-router')

const routerWithoutNew = Router()
```

I thought it was an error, but I was surprised to see it working properly.

```js
const Router = require('koa-router')

const routerWithNew = new Router()
```

and, it works fine, too.

what is difference between `routerWithoutNew` and `routerWithNew`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are treated identically due to the following line in the Koa Router source code:

```js
if (!(this instanceof Router)) return new Router(opts);
```

(from https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/56735f009768e32cce89af60337e7e2a8d6bbbc4/lib/router.js#L51)